# Multivariable Weierstrass preparation theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-numbers

The Weierstrass preparation theorem for formal power series says the following:

> Let $f(T) \in \mathbf{Z}_p [[ T ]]$ be a formal power series. Then we can write $f(T) = p^{\mu} \cdot u(T) \cdot g(T)$, where $u(T) \in \mathbf{Z}_p [[ T ]]^{\times}$ is a unit and $g(T)$ is a distinguished polynomial.

(A polynomial $g(T) \in \mathbf{Z}_p [[ T ]]$ is *distinguished* if when you reduce it modulo $p$, only the highest degree term remains.)

**My question:** Is there a version of this theorem for multivariable power series, i.e: power series in $\mathbf{Z}_p [[ T_1, \dots, T_n ]]$? Given a power series $f \in \mathbf{Z}_p [[ T_1, \dots, T_n ]]$, can we write it as
$$f(T_1, \dots, T_n) = p^{\mu} \cdot u(T_1, \dots, T_n) \cdot g(T_1, \dots, T_n)$$
where $u$ belongs to $\mathbf{Z}_p [[ T_1, \dots, T_n ]]^{\times}$ and $g$ is a "distinguished polynomial" (whatever distinguished means in this setting)?

Comment: See books on rigid analytic geometry, e.g., Bosch, Güntzer, and Remmert's *Non-Archimedean Analysis: A Systematic Approach to Rigid Analytic Geometry*. They have a Weierstrass Preparation Theorem and Weierstrass Division Theorem for Tate algebras. Apply them when the coefficients are all integral.  This is all motivated by the original work of Weierstrass in several complex variables ($p$-adic analysis was developed later).

Comment: @KConrad Thanks for the reference. The theorems in this book only talk about power series where the $p$-adic valuation of the coefficients goes to zero (i.e: Tate algebras). Is there a Weierstrass Preparation Theorem in the case of arbitrary power series (i.e: where the coefficients don't go to zero)?

Comment: Ah, good point.  There are two versions of WPT for single-variable power series: the one you knew in $\mathbf Z_p[[T]]$ and the one in the book I mentioned for series with coefficents tending to $0$. They need not be the same when applied to a series in the smaller ring, since the two rings have different unit groups. Compare the two versions for single-variable power series, look at the version for multivariable Tate series, and that should suggest a version for multivariable formal power series.

Comment: Or see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404068/generalizing-the-weierstrass-preparation-theorem-to-formal-power-series-in-multi and replace $K$ there with $\mathbf Z_p$.